Laravel Inertia with Vue.js doesn't reload
I installed a Laravel Inertia project with Vue and hot reload doesn't do his job even if I F5.
For modifications to apply on my frontend, I need to stop the dev script and restart it for example if I change the content of a <p>
I'm using Laravel 11 with Vue 3 (Vite).
Here are my files :
vite.config.js :
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: 'resources/js/app.js',
            ssr: 'resources/js/ssr.js',
            refresh: true,
        }),
        vue({
            template: {
                transformAssetUrls: {
                    base: null,
                    includeAbsolute: false,
                },
            },
        }),
    ],
});

app.js :
import './bootstrap';
import '../css/app.css';
import 'remixicon/fonts/remixicon.css';

import { createApp, h } from 'vue';
import { createInertiaApp } from '@inertiajs/vue3';
import { resolvePageComponent } from 'laravel-vite-plugin/inertia-helpers';
import { ZiggyVue } from '../../vendor/tightenco/ziggy';
import { createI18n } from 'vue-i18n';
import * as Sentry from '@sentry/vue';

const appName = import.meta.env.VITE_APP_NAME || 'Laravel';

createInertiaApp({
    title: (title) => `${title} - ${appName}`,
    resolve: (name) =>
        resolvePageComponent(`./Pages/${name}.vue`, import.meta.glob('./Pages/**/*.vue')),
    setup({ el, App, props, plugin }) {
        const locales = props.initialPage.props.locales;
        let locale = Object.keys(locales).includes(navigator.language) ? navigator.language : 'fr';

        if (localStorage.getItem('locale')) {
            locale = localStorage.getItem('locale');
        } else {
            localStorage.setItem('locale', locale);
        }

        const app = createApp({ render: () => h(App, props) });

        Sentry.init({
            app,
            dsn: import.meta.env.VITE_SENTRY_DSN,
            integrations: [
                Sentry.replayIntegration({
                    maskAllText: false,
                    blockAllMedia: false,
                }),
            ],
            // Session Replay
            replaysSessionSampleRate: 0.1,
            replaysOnErrorSampleRate: 1.0,
        });

        app.use(plugin)
            .use(ZiggyVue)
            .use(
                createI18n({
                    locale:
                        props.initialPage.props.auth?.user?.locale ??
                        locale ??
                        props.initialPage.props.appLocale,
                    fallbackLocale: props.initialPage.props.appLocale,
                    messages: props.initialPage.props.localeMessages,
                }),
            )
            .mount(el);

        return app;
    },
    progress: {
        color: '#4B5563',
    },
});

app.blade.php :
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <title inertia>{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}</title>

        <!-- Fonts -->
        @googlefonts(['font' => 'Poppins','nonce' => csp_nonce()])

        <!-- Scripts -->
        @routes(nonce: csp_nonce())
        @vite(['resources/js/app.js', "resources/js/Pages/{$page['component']}.vue"])
        @inertiaHead
    </head>
    <x-impersonate::banner/>
    <body class="antialiased h-lvh overflow-hidden">
        @inertia
    </body>
</html>

Did i missconfigured something ?

The conclusions are wrong, hot reload is when a page is not reloaded. F5 is page reload. It physically cannot force an app to rebuild. If your problem is that dev server doesn't rebuild the app when you change files, then please, explain in details what you observe. There's no  in code you posted. Does this happen for any changes or some? What exactly is "dev script"? What does dev server console say when you make changes?
